# Google Places API doesn't restrict results to given radius parameter

Tags: node.js, google-maps, google-api, google-places

I'm using this code in NodeJS to retrieve the results:

```
return googleMaps.places({
              language: 'en',
              query: keywords,
              location: [loc.lat, loc.lng],
              radius: 5000
            })
```

As you can see, there's a restriction for 5000 meters max. For some reason I got results from another city which is about 50KM away from that lat, lng (some of the results were in the relevant distance, half were not..)

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're using Google's Place Text Search service. The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#TextSearchRequests) states:

> **radius** — Defines the distance (in meters) within which to **bias** place
>   results. The maximum allowed radius is 50 000 meters. Results inside
>   of this region will be ranked higher than results outside of the
>   search circle; however, prominent results from outside of the search
>   radius may be included.
>
> You may bias results to a specified circle by passing a location and a
>   radius parameter. This will instruct the Google Places service to
>   prefer showing results within that circle. **Results outside the defined
>   area may still be displayed.** Biasing results to a region or circle is
>   recommended to improve relevance of results for otherwise ambiguous
>   queries.

So this appears to be expected behavior from the API. There is no way to fully restrict Text Search results within a given location/radius.

Hope this helps!